# New column added to table is not saving

Tags: model

I have added a new column to the newsletter_subscriber table, 'artists_followed'. in my overridden `Mage_Newsletter_Model_Subscriber` model class, I have added the following function:

```
public function updateSubscriberArtists($email, $artist) {
    $this->loadByEmail($email);
    if ($this->getId()) {
        $this->setArtistsFollowed($artist);

        try {
            $this->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            throw new Exception($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

everything runs ok, no errors are thrown, but when I look in the database, the new column is not populated.

My table is:

```
CREATE TABLE `mage_newsletter_subscriber` (
  `subscriber_id` int(7) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `store_id` smallint(5) unsigned DEFAULT '0',
  `change_status_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `customer_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subscriber_email` varchar(150) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_general_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  `subscriber_status` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `subscriber_confirm_code` varchar(32) DEFAULT 'NULL',
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `campaign_source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `artists_followed` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`subscriber_id`),
  KEY `FK_SUBSCRIBER_CUSTOMER` (`customer_id`),
  KEY `FK_NEWSLETTER_SUBSCRIBER_STORE` (`store_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK_NEWSLETTER_SUBSCRIBER_STORE` FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) REFERENCES `mage_core_store` (`store_id`) ON DELETE SET NULL ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Newsletter subscribers';
```

I'm racking my brain on this one. Any ideas? Am i missing something completely obvious?

Comment: I have the same issue. Added an attribute (column) in SalesRule, despite the model has that field correctly set, it never updates the database.

Comment: If someone uses n98-magerun, maybe this could help: `./n98-magerun cache:flush` :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, i got it to work by changing `$this->setArtistsFollowed($artist)` to `$this->setData('artists_followed', $artist)`. i'm not sure why that worked though? what happened to the magic setter in this instance?

Comment: What does "echo typeof($this);" return?

Comment: is that a magento-specific method? i'm getting Fatal error: Call to undefined function typeof() when i use that.

Comment: Wow. My brain is fried on Javascript lol :) Sorry, try this: `echo get_class($this);`

Comment: it's returning my overridden class. it's odd, i have another field that i added to this table, and using the magic setter works there, just not in this instance.

Answer (score 43):

Another problem can be:

Zend_Db cached the structure of the database tables. If you add a new column, refresh the cache and Zend knows to fill the table.

> Even if you have all cache disabled, the database structure and other info may still be cached.

Thanks james.c.funk

**Make sure you delete everything in `var/cache`, this happens ,when you hit the button in the top but NOT when you check all checkboxes and refresh them!**

Comment: do you mean the magento cache? or is there another cache that is zend-only?

Comment: I have the same problem, but clearing the cache does not work for me.

Comment: Even if you have all cache disabled, the database structure and other info may still be cached.

Comment: Fixed the problem i was facing, only I needed to flush both Cache Storage and Magento Storage!

Comment: Thx @FabianBlechschmidt was looking for a reason my values wasn't stored, clearing the chache solved the issue.

Comment: Thnx  @FabianBlechschmidt this was driving me crazy

Comment: Please stop thanking me in comments but instead upvote. We need the comment section for actual comments :-)

Comment: Thnx @FabianBlechschmidt Cache clearing solved the problem

Comment: waaaaa...this solved my problem man. Thank you!

Comment: Sooo frustrated about this! Was refreshing caches like crazy using the checkboxes (even flushed Magento Cache using the button). Eventually I found this answer & clicked "Flush Cache Storage" which resolved it for me. Such an aggressive caching mechanism :| Thanks @FabianBlechschmidt

Answer (score 1):

You need to **Flush Cache Storage.**

You can do this through backend:

> System -> Cache Management -> Click on 'Flush Cache Storage' button.